# Prevent default events of medium-editor

Tags: javascript, medium-editor

How would i replace internally triggered events of medium-editor with my custom ones or simply change internally designed behaviour?

In this hierarchy

```
<div>
<textarea class='editable'></textarea>
</div>
```

I bind a click handler to the `div` and do `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.preventDefault()`.

I also try adding after the instantiating of medium-editor.

```
var editor = new MediumEditor('.editable')
.subscribe("editableClick", function(e){

e.preventDefault();

});
```

Every way i try `textarea` gets focused and cursor starts to blink.

For example intial click event adds an element to the dom with a class `.medium-editor-element` should i dive to source to modify this behaviour?

Or maybe i would like it to work with not a click but a double click.

Anyone familiar with the internal workings of medium-editor?

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error and the help of dev tools i found the way to do what i want. 
But i think this question is still answerable because i did it by modifying the source of `medium-editor`.

So, in `medium-editor.js` in line 2725 there is `setupListener` function.

There are 3 main events attached there to `case 'externalInteraction':` 2731th line.

`mousedown`,`click`,`focus`.

Starting from 2959th line there are the attached handlers for those events.

`handleBodyClick`,`handleBodyFocus`,`handleBodyMousedown`

The `mousedown` is important for my case because **it is the first one that fires** and should be prevented and accepted in different cases.

In the end i added a `dblclick` and `handleBodyDblClick` to source then put some logic in `handleBodyMousedown` to prevent the default behaviour of `mousedown` event in some cases.

Anyway, from the source as i can understand there are no override methods or hooks to modify `medium-editor` internal events.

It would be nice to have that feature.
Or if i am wrong i would like to know if there is a better way to do all these.